# Getting all records from Elasticsearch using Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to get all the records from Elasticsearch using Java API. But I receive the below error

> n[[Wild Thing][localhost:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]];
>   nested: QueryPhaseExecutionException[Result window is too large, from
>   + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10101].

My code is as below

```
Client client;
try {
    client = TransportClient.builder().build().
            addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
    int from = 1;
    int to = 100;
    while (from <= 131881) {
        SearchResponse response = client
                .prepareSearch("demo_risk_data")
                .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH).setFrom(from)
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.termQuery("user_agent", "")))
                .setSize(to).setExplain(true).execute().actionGet();
        if (response.getHits().getHits().length > 0) {
            for (SearchHit searchData : response.getHits().getHits()) {
                JSONObject value = new JSONObject(searchData.getSource());
                System.out.println(value.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Total number of records currently present are 131881 ,so I start with `from = 1` and `to = 100` and then get 100 records until `from <= 131881`. Is there are way where I can check get records in set of say 100 until there are no further records in Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do so using the [scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html), which the Java client [also supports](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-scrolling.html).

You can do it like this:

```
Client client;
try {
    client = TransportClient.builder().build().
            addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

    QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.termQuery("user_agent", ""));
    SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch("demo_risk_data")
        .addSort(SortParseElement.DOC_FIELD_NAME, SortOrder.ASC)
        .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
        .setQuery(qb)
        .setSize(100).execute().actionGet();

    //Scroll until no hits are returned
    while (true) {
        //Break condition: No hits are returned
        if (scrollResp.getHits().getHits().length == 0) {
            break;
        }

        // otherwise read results
        for (SearchHit hit : scrollResp.getHits().getHits()) {
            JSONObject value = new JSONObject(searchData.getSource());
            System.out.println(value.toString());
        }

        // prepare next query
        scrollResp = client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollResp.getScrollId()).setScroll(new TimeValue(60000)).execute().actionGet();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of set a constant value to the size (100). Is some posibility to get all the values that is stored in the elastic?

Comment: @Val, Can u update your answer with latest API?. Now `TransportClient` and some are deprecated.

Comment: @PaulSteven if you follow the second link, you'll see how it looks like now ;-)