# Retrieve documents from elasticsearch 2.3.4 java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to get a cursor on elasticsearch which could be iterated over the entire set of documents.

I am using match all query , and the index has max 17,00,000 documents .

I tired using `response.getHits().getHits();` , but it gets me only 10 docs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669046/getting-all-records-from-elasticsearch-using-java-api/37669582#37669582 (hint: use the scroll API)

Comment: Thanks Val...Perfectly achieved

Comment: Cool ! Feel free to upvote if it helped.