# delete all elements which is less than a value in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, query-builder, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have the following saved json data in Elasticsearch:

```
   {
   "id":"1234",
   "expirationDate":"17343234234",
   "paths":"http:localhost:9090",
   "work":"software dev",
   "family":{
      "baba":"jams",
      "mother":"ela"
   }
},
{
   "id":"00021",
   "expirationDate":"0123234",
   "paths":"http:localhost:8080",
   "work":"software engi",
   "family":{
      "baba":"stev",
      "mother":"hela"
   }
}
```

i want to delete all list of **ids** which its **expirationDate** are smaller than today using QueryBuilder in springdata Elasticsearch

Comment: How many ids in the results do you expect approximately?

Comment: I want to get all ids

Comment: my question is how much is all? 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 1M? the solution depends on that answer

Comment: More than 10000

Comment: Ok, then you're not going to be able to get them all in one shot, is that ok for you?

Comment: Yes but what is the reason for that?

Comment: And I'm just curious about the condition... all items created before today, pretty much means all items, right? since there are no items created in the future... or are there?

Comment: Exactly that what i want to get

Comment: The reason is that by default, ES will only return 10K hits. You can lift that limit, but the can be performance implications... It'd help to know your use case in more details.

Comment: Okay what is the best solution for that plz, i want to get all old entities, means before today

Comment: Well not all items, in more details there well be expire date which is 3 days ahead, but i am fucusing on this small example just for demo

Comment: Plz see updated post, i mean expirationDate

Comment: Because if i check whether expirationDate before today then the item is expired

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223476/discussion-between-catalina-and-val).

Comment: Here is a solution that would work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37669582/4604579, it might need some adaptation given it was for an older version, but the concept is explained there, i.e. scrolled search.

Comment: Could u please adapt the solution with elastcsearch 7.6 which i am using, would very thankfull

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) is the way to go.

```
POST /{your_index_name}/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "expirationDate": {
        "lt": "{your_timestamp}"
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

The [java client documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/7.9/java-docs-delete-by-query.html#java-docs-delete-by-query) indicates you can build a request this way:

```
BulkByScrollResponse response =
  new DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder(client, DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE)
    .filter(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("gender", "male")) 
    .source("persons")                                  
    .get();                                             
long deleted = response.getDeleted();
```

This is marked as [supported by Spring-data-elasticsearch since version 3.2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#new-features.3-2-0).

You can for example use [query derivation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts) :

> In addition to query methods, query derivation for both count and delete queries is available.

In the Appendix C, you can see that `IsLessThan` is a query derivation keyword, which means something along these lines ought to be supported out of the box :

```
interface YourRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
  long deleteByExpirationDateIsLessThan(long timestamp);
}
```

By using query derivation,  you are letting spring do the implementation (fingers crossed that it will do "the right thing").

But you can also use a [`ElasticsearchRestTemplate#delete`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplate.html) (if you are using the older `ElasticsearchTemplate`, this works the same).

This allows you to pass in any spring-data query (Native, String, or criteria).

Comment: but how to create a function supporting this query using QueryBuilder or similar API?or DeleteRequestBuilder in springboot

Comment: I've added details, but really, this is just standard Spring data / Spring es stuff.

Comment: i have last questoin please, is there any way to update all expirationDate to be currenttime? so is expiratonDAte less than currenttime thaen update to todays time please help me

Comment: There kind of is, but elasticsearch is not optimized for this at all so it is extremely costly (it basically entails rebuilding the whole index). But this is another question altogether so please ask in a separate question.

Comment: please help me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64771780/updating-elasticsearch-entities-with-bulk-without-id-parameters